# OpenLayers - how to use single and double click event on feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using Opnelayers control for selection of feature

```
OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature
```

when I triggered the single click event then feature get selected and its working fine for me. Now I want to use double click event for another operation.

I have get the idea from this link [feature to have both a single click and double click event?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/33351)

I have used the same code and both click events working fine but I cannot get the feature on which click event performed. This is the code

```
handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
    select,
    {
        click: function(evt)
        {
        
            var feature = this.layer.getFeatureFromEvent(evt);
            
            console.log(feature); // output null
            
            if(this.layer.selectedFeatures){
                this.unselect(this.layer.selectedFeatures[0]);
            }
        },
        dblclick: function(evt)
        {
            // some other operation
        }
    },
    {
        single: true,
        double: true,
        stopDouble: true,
        stopSingle: true
    }
);

handler.activate();
```

Any idea which thing is missing in this code?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For The Above Question this might solve your answer with few changes

```
var handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
layerName, { 
  click: function(evt) {
    console.log('click has triggered');
    var feature = layerName.getFeatureFromEvent(evt);
  }
  ,dblclick: function(evt) {
    console.log('dblclick has triggered');
  }
},{
  single: true  
  ,double: true
  ,stopSingle: true
  ,stopDouble: true
}  
);
handler.activate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been in a similar situation and used the getClosestFeatureToCoordinate method of the layer source. The code would be something like:

```
click: function(evt) {
    var coord = evt.coordinate;
    var source = this.layer.getSource();
    var feature = source.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(coord);
    // do something with feature
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am using openlayers 2.x version. I have not found layer.getSource() function in this version.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm not too familiar with the 2.x version. Have you tried working with the OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature class? There's an example at http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/select-feature.html

Answer (score 0):

I have done in this way.

```
click: function(evt) {

    var pos = map.getLonLatFromPixel(xy);
    var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(pos.lon, pos.lat);


    var list = $.map(this.layer.features, function(v) {
            return v.geometry.distanceTo(point);
    }); // get distance of all features

    var min = (Math.min.apply(null, list)); // minimum distance

    var closest = $.map(this.layer.features, function(v) {
            if (v.geometry.distanceTo(point) == min)
                    return v;
    });


    feature = closest[0];
```

}